# Flutter no se instala correctamente

Tags: flutter, dart, programación-móvil

quiero instalar Flutter, pero al ejecutar el comando "flutter doctor" me saltan estos errores:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo entendido que no es necesario instalar Android Studio ni Visual Studio, ya que yo uso Visual Studio Code, ¿Alguien sabe que pasa?
Gracias.

Comment: lo mejor es que instales android studio que viene con el sdk manager y demás cosas.

Comment: ¿Pero es necesario? No he usado nunca Android Studio

Answer (score 1):

Android Studio es necesario solo para la instalación(Para la instalación de todas las dependencias Android), a pesar que no uses el IDE como tal.
En mi caso uso VSCode, pero tengo instalado Android Studio, puedes ver más info en la documentación oficial:

https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/macos#android-setup

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para instalar lo mencionado, abres Android Studio -> Preferences y luego vas a la siguiente opción:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ya tengo instalado Android Studio, pero a la hora de aceptar las licencias de Android me salta este error:
Android sdkmanager not found. Update to the latest Android SDK and ensure that the cmdline-tools are installed to
resolve this.
Tengo la ultima versión de Android Studio instalada

Comment: seguiste el paso 2 que menciona? Start Android Studio, and go through the ‘Android Studio Setup Wizard’. This installs the latest Android SDK, Android SDK Command-line Tools, and Android SDK Build-Tools, which are required by Flutter when developing for Android.

Comment: el android studio tiene un SDK manager en sus opciones, en el cual debes instalar el android sdk command line tools y build tools.

Comment: Si lo he instalado todo, de hecho ahora estoy dentro de un proyecto de prueba que he hecho, pero no veo la opción de SDK manager.

Comment: ahí actualicé mi respuesta

Comment: Vale ya lo he solucionado, pero ahora me saltan estos dos errores:
android-studio-dir = C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start
Android Studio not found at C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start

Comment: https://fluttercorner.com/android-studio-not-installed-when-run-flutter-doctor-while-android-studio

Answer (score 0):

parce respecto a visual studio, dices que ya lo usas pero busca como instalar el paquete de C++, me pasó exactamente lo mismo y seguí unos pasitos sencillos para que descargara eso y ya, listo ese error

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).